# why the original number dont change place in array in maltab

Tags: arrays, matlab

from my previous coding, this my latest one..
i want to change the direction of the original 2 to right direction & at the same time a new number 2 appear in the 3x3 matrix

```
 m=zeros(3); m(randi(numel(m)))=2
```

ans=

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
2 0 0
```

that was among the expected random answer of the original 2 then i pick the direction

```
case 'right'
   %number= find(m);

   if (m>=7);
     circshift(m,[0 0]);
        m_subset = setdiff(find(m),numel(m));

         m(randi(numel(m))) = 2   
         count=0;
   elseif (m>=4) | (m<=6);

      circshift(m,[0 1]);
        m_subset = setdiff(find(m),numel(m));

        m(randi(numel(m))) = 2

   elseif (m<4);    

      circshift(m,[0 2]);
        m_subset = setdiff(find(m),numel(m)) ;

        m(randi(numel(m))) = 2

   else
       msgbox('next');
   end
```

the expected answer is

```
0 0 0
0 2 0
0 0 2
```

where the original number 2 go the right direction & a random 2 appears. 
but the coding above did not make the original number change direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `circshift` this does not alter the input `m` in place. You need to re-assign to `m` *after* calling `circshift`.

```
m = circshift(m, [0, 2]);
```

Also for your conditionals you should be comparing `number` and not `m`. Instead of that though, I would use the second output of `find` to figure out the column and use that.

```
[r,c] = find(m);

%// If column 1
if c == 1
    %// do thing
elseif c == 2
    %// do other thing
else
    %// do yet another thing.
end
```